# Laravel - Display input datetime-local value

Tags: html, laravel, datetime, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to display my database date value on input datetime-local how can I do it? Ive added `value="$aircraftFlight->flight_date"` but it is not working

here is my **input datetime-local**

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="flight_date" class="form-control">
```

here is my **$variable->dataname**

```
$aircraftFlight->iata_flight_number
```

Answer (score 0):

You can format date :
     if your date is not formatted already:

```
 $datetimevalue= strtotime($aircraftFlight->flight_date);
 $formatted = date('Y-m-d', $datetimevalue);
```

else

```
 $formatted = $aircraftFlight->flight_date->format('Y-m-d);
```

in html:

```
<input type="date" name="flight_date" class="form-control" value="{{$formatted}}"/>
```

Can also use Carbon in laravel for formatting purpose. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: it has an error here **Call to a member function format() on string**

Comment: i've solved my answer just by changing the format .. the format of datetime-local is complicated 1 line then it will give you nothing

Answer (score 0):

Try this one,

```
{{date('Y-m-d',strtotime($aircraftFlight->flight_date))}}
```

you have to change string to date at first and then format in to desired type.